# sqlite: disk I/O error & file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: c++, linux, database, sqlite

I use work system is linux, and my sqlite3 version is 3.9.2(2015-11-02)

I have implemented an system which interact with sqlite.

I need to store and write db frequently.An error occurred 2 or 3 times recently.

From my log, there is a disk I/O error followed by another error :file is encrypted or is not a database. After that, this db is will become unusable. What conditions will cause this phenomenon? ,Thank you.

```
"
1:select SEQ from InvEvent Where id=4 AND CHead=22;
2:INSERT INTO InvEvent (ID,CHead,Code,RTC,UploadRTC) VALUES (4,22,0,0,0);
3:select SEQ from InvEvent Where id=4 AND CHead=22;
4:Update InvEvent set ID=4,CHead=22,Code=225,RTC=1591997623,UploadRTC=0 Where SEQ=8;
1:select SEQ from InvEvent Where id=4 AND CHead=21;
2:INSERT INTO InvEvent (ID,CHead,Code,RTC,UploadRTC) VALUES (4,21,0,0,0);
3:select SEQ from InvEvent Where id=4 AND CHead=21;
4:Update InvEvent set ID=4,CHead=21,Code=226,RTC=1591997623,UploadRTC=0 Where SEQ=9;
Retry SQL error: disk I/O error
"
"
Retry SQL error: file is encrypted or is not a database
Error Cause: update SyncLog set RTC5Min=1592670300,Energy=0 where ID=4;
"
```

Comment: If you turn on extended error codes (Assuming a version of sqlite that old even supports them), and can recreate it, you can get a more detailed error. See https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html

Comment: OK, thank you, but it is not easy to happen. Is there any possibility other than spending time waiting for this message?